# What is the difference between doing Windows syscalls with hand-written wrappers vs. copying machine code from ntdll?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I am wondering what the difference between these two methods of syscalls are.

First method creates an assembly file with the op codes found in the dll and externs a function prototype to call the assembly.

Second method opens the dll, copies the bytes at the start of the function into a RWE buffer, then casts it to function and execute.

First method:
syscall.asm

```
.code
    SysNtCreateFile proc
            mov r10, rcx
            mov eax, 55h
            syscall
            ret
    SysNtCreateFile endp
end
```

main.c

```
.. includes and other setup
EXTERN_C NTSTATUS SysNtCreateFile(
    PHANDLE FileHandle, 
    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, 
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes, 
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, 
    PLARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize, 
    ULONG FileAttributes, 
    ULONG ShareAccess, 
    ULONG CreateDisposition, 
    ULONG CreateOptions, 
    PVOID EaBuffer, 
    ULONG EaLength);

We have out function extern and now we can just call it...

SysNtCreateFile(....)
Which calls the assembly.
```

Second method:

```
1. Open and read ntdll.dll
2. Locate the function SysNtCreateFile()

char sysntcreatefilebytes[20] = {0};
Set the buffer above to executable

Copy the 20 bytes at the SysNtCreateFile location into the buffer above

NTSTATUS (*SysNtCreateFile)(PHANDLE, ACCESS_MASK, ...)

SysNtCreateFile myfunc = sysntcreatefilebytes;

myfunc(..., ..., ...))
```

Comment: One required you to write a lot of assembly code and will miserably fail as soon as the first patch Tuesday comes. The other one will require you to use hacky techniques and will miserably fail as soon as the first patch Tuesday comes. Both are very very bad, non-portable, ways to use the Windows Kernel. This looks like an XY problem, do you mind explaining why can't you simply use the DLLs instead?

Comment: What would cause an issue with the 2nd method? If the syscall number gets updated it would be updated in the DLL and would be copied and executed.

Comment: It could break if the DLL function is longer than 20 bytes next time.  (That's fixable by using a buffer that's plenty large.)  Harder to fix is the possibility that the instructions do RIP-relative access to some static data.  Or even a relative jump to another function somewhere else in the DLL (e.g. it becomes a wrapper for some new DLL function or system call).  Those are less likely, but can't be ruled out.  Probably not the *first* patch Tuesday, but some future one.

Comment: I can see the appeal of not using the DLL at all, to make self-contained code.  But if you had to open NTDLL to get the machine code, why wouldn't you just map it and call into it, preferably using the normal dynamic-linking mechanisms?

Comment: @nahjoh44 Microsoft has changed their DLLs widely, for example introducing the ApiSetSchema. DLLs that were doing syscalls directly now forward to other DLLs. The syscall mechanism itself can change, maybe one day it will be requiring more than 20 bytes, or won't embed a `syscall` in the code or will use some per-module context that is initialized by the loader. In short, the "syscalls" of Windows are its DLL, if you bypass them you may run into troubles. It's doable if you keep your software updated and test it on every release of Windows.

Comment: @MargaretBloom "maybe one day it will be requiring more than 20 bytes," (whispering) Just between you and me: It's now 24 bytes. Oh, and it doesn't always use `syscall`.

Comment: DLL stands for "dynamically-linked library." The intent is to have a set of helper functions that doesn't need to be loaded into your program at all times, just when it's needed. That way your `.exe` file isn't bloated with logic that you'll only use a couple of times.